# ng-content in child and parent does not appear

Tags: angular

I have this child-parent structure in my project:

```
<app-parent>
   parent component
   <ng-content select=["parent"]></ng-content>
   <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>

<app-child>
  child component
  <ng-content select=["child"]></ng-content>
<app-child>

<app-root>
   <app-parent>
      <span parent>this should appear in parent </span>
      <span child> this should appear in child </span>
   </app-parent>
<app-root>
```

the problem is the child span is not appearing. How should i do it?

Comment: Where is `</app-child>` in parent?

Comment: Sorry, muy mistake, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing it to the child component:

```
<app-parent>
   parent component
   <ng-content select="[parent]"></ng-content>
   <app-child>
        <ng-content select="[child]" ngProjectAs="[child]"> </ng-content>
   </app-child>
</app-parent>
```

Comment: I can not do this, I need to use the structure I show in my post, i mean, what is going to be included in child is only known by the root

Comment: well, I don't think you can do it without _passing_ it to the child component one way or another, the same way you're passing it now to the parent, which is why it reads it, and child doesn't, because it's not passed..

Comment: oh sorry, first time I missunderstood, with your comment is clear and it works perfect! thanks